# Upload images to a newly created domain using PHP

Tags: php, image, dns, cross-domain

**Use Case**:Working on a project where user can create his own site and publish it to internet.(Something similar to [this](http://www.wix.com) or [this](http://app.imcreator.com)). The user can **create and later edit** his website.When the user wants to publish we create a domain of his choice(a subdomain at first.Can be a different domain later).

**Issue**:What we want to do is,have the images stored directly on the domain created for the user(The domain initially would be created as a subdomain).For example,our site is at www.xyz.com,then the subdomain can be ABC.xyz.com.This will help to maintain a single copy of images for both the publish and the edit domain.We don't want to store the same image at two different locations.

**Research**:
Two possibilities that I found could be used:
 
1) Have a php **upload script**(`upload.php`) on each domain created that would be called when user uploads any image.-->**Not sure how efficient it would be**
2) Use FTP to transfer images from a domain to another.(Some cross domain mechanism)**-->Not sure about the security issues here**

Do I need to have any kind of cross domain script to be written?Please,help me with how to go about the issue.I don't want the entire code but the logic that would take me in the right direction.**Suggestions,if my approach is wrong are welcome**.Thank you for your time.
**Note:** I am still figuring out other alternatives.If I get my code in some shape,will update it.

Comment: I think upload.php would be enough

Comment: But would creating it on each domain be good?Can I have centralised script for all  the domains?Thank you for the inputs @E L

Comment: Are these two domains on the different servers? Do you not control one of the two servers?

Comment: @sach learner: as I understood, abc.xyz.com is equal to abc.com (cname or something), so U need only one php script for uploads for each domain. I mean one 'upload.php' file at every domain.

Comment: @Sammitch initially they'd be on the same server as we will be creating a sub domain for them!!later the user may ask to host it on some other server which he owns or buys!!:P

Comment: @E L abc.xyz.com is a sub domain so abc.com and abc.xyz.com would be different I believe!!abc.com would be an entirely different domain!!

Comment: @EL If I attach the script with each domain,what would be the **security** issues attached to it?Also,I want to move the `html` files(template that user has created) to his domain later when he publishes.So,can I directly copy the files from one domain to other? or I need to have some FTP mechanism?

Comment: @sach learner, if you want security, then use https protocol. Both ftp and http transfers are insecure.

Comment: I haven't worked on `https` yet,but wil study it.If you can point me to any tutorial or example to start with,it would be great!!Also,if you add an answer with a few details regarding **copying files from one domain to other** and the image uploading part,I would be able to accept it and **close the thread**!Thank you very much.@EL